# Sequelize Eeager Loading Error - Can't figure out include

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, error-handling, sequelize.js

I'm working with sequelize on an Angular and Nodejs built application. I've built a User model that hasMany notfications as a sender and hasMany notifications as a receiver. The notifications model also belongsTo User as a sender and belongsTo user as receiver. My issue is when I try to implement a GET http request on the notifications, I am receiving a Sequelize Eager Loading Error. I've commented out the include statement, as well as the notifications attribute on user, and the GET request works. I just don't understand what is causing the error.

Here are my models.

"use strict";

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Notification = sequelize.define("Notification", {
    startAddress: DataTypes.STRING,
    endAddress: DataTypes.STRING,
    tripDate: DataTypes.DATE,
    tripHour: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    numberOfPassengers: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    price: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      defaultValue: -1
    }
  });
  Notification.associate = function(models) {
    Notification.belongsTo(models.User, {
      as: "sender",
      onDelete: "CASCADE",
      foreignKey: "senderId"
    });
    Notification.belongsTo(models.User, {
      as: "receiver",
      onDelete: "CASCADE",
      foreignKey: "receiverId"
    });
  };
  return Notification;
};



"use strict";

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var User = sequelize.define("User", {
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
    profileImgUrl: DataTypes.STRING,
    fName: DataTypes.STRING,
    lName: DataTypes.STRING,
    yearOfBirth: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    gender: DataTypes.STRING,
    ratings: {
      type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.INTEGER),
      defaultValue: [5]
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      defaultValue: sequelize.literal('NOW()')
    },
    updatedAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      defaultValue: sequelize.literal('NOW()')
    }
  });
  User.associate = function(models) {
    User.hasMany(models.RideRequest, {
      onDelete: "CASCADE",
      foreignKey: "riderId"
    });
    User.hasMany(models.DriveRequest, {
      onDelete: "CASCADE",
      foreignKey: "driverId"
    });
    User.hasMany(models.Notification, {
      as: 'sender',
      onDelete: "CASCADE",
      foreignKey: "senderId"
    });
    User.hasMany(models.Notification, {
      as: 'receiver',
      onDelete: "CASCADE",
      foreignKey: "receiverId"
    });
  };
  return User;
};
```

And here is my notifications controller, which holds the logic for the notifications routes.

```
list: function list(req,res) {
    var decoded = jwt.decode(req.query.token);
    return model.User.findOne({
      where: {id: decoded.user.id},
      include: [{
        model: model.Notification
      }]
    }).then(function (user) {
        let ratingAv;
        for (let rating of user.ratings) {
          ratingAv = (user.ratings.length/(rating += rating)*10);
        }
        console.log(ratingAv + ' RATINGSSSS');
        let resObj = Object.assign({}, {
          id: user.id,
          profileImgUrl: user.profileImgUrl,
          fName: user.fName,
          lName: user.lName,
          yearOfBirth: user.yearOfBirth,
          gender: user.gender,
          ratings: ratingAv,
          notifications: user.Notifications.map(function(notification) {
            return Object.assign({}, {
              id: notification.id,
              startAddress: notification.startAddress,
              endAddress: notification.endAddress,
              tripDate: notification.tripDate,
              tripHour: notification.tripHour,
              numberOfPassengers: notification.numberOfPassengers,
              price: notification.price,
              senderId: notification.senderId,
              receiverId: notification.receiverId
            });
          })
        });
      return res.status(201).json({
        message: 'Notifications retrieved successfully',
        obj: resObj
      });
    }).catch(function (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        title: 'There was an error retrieving notifications',
        error: err
      });
    });
  },
```

If I could even get a better error somehow, I'd be able to figure it out. The error is very generalized and doesn't help me understand what may be misspelled, misplaced or etc. Can anyone figure out what the issue is?

Answer (score 1):

I was missing the as: parameter in my include option. If you are using multiple instances of the same model on the same model (as User, User both on Notification), then you need to use Aliases to identify them with the as: option on include: . Good luck!